# Partial Differentiation Chain Rule Issue

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have a small doubt regarding the following partial differentiation.

$h=g(x,w,s), s = g(y, w, t)$. And it is given $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial w} = 0, \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial w} = 0$

I am trying to calculate $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w}$ as follows.

$$
\dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} =\dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} \times \dfrac{\partial w} {\partial w} + \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial s} \times \dfrac{\partial s} {\partial w} 
$$

$$
= \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} + \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial s} \times \dfrac{\partial s} {\partial w}
$$

But this ends up in a weird form $a = a + b$ where $a = \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w}, b =  \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial s} \times \dfrac{\partial s} {\partial w}$

Can somebody point out the mistake that I am making here?

Comment: $2\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w}=\dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} \times \dfrac{\partial w} {\partial w} + \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial s} \times \dfrac{\partial s} {\partial w}$ I think that's a mistake

Comment: The $\frac{\partial h}{ \partial w}$ on the left hand side is not the same $\frac{\partial h}{ \partial w}$ as appears on the right hand side. The LHS one is really $\frac{\partial H}{ \partial w}$ where $H(x,y,w,t)=h(x,w,g(y,w,t))$

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivatives are named that because the result depends not just on the numerator and denominator variables, but on what other independent variables are chosen with the denominator to make a complete coordinate system. This is because the partial derivative is the derivative with respect to one variable, *while the other independent variables are held constant*. Holding a different set of variables constant will change how the function responds to the variable with respect to which you are differentiating. To evaluate $\frac{\partial h}{\partial w}$, you have to know what other variables, *independent of $w$*, are used to create a complete coordinate system (that is, the selected variables completely determine the values of all the other variables, and for no smaller subset of the selected variables is this still true).

There are two ways to approach this:

- If $w, s$ are to be the set of independent variables, then $s = g(y, w, t)$ is not a way of finding $s$, but rather a constraint on $t$ (since $y$ is already established as a dependent variable). This constraint makes $t$ dependent.
- If $s$ should be considered dependent on $w$, then $s = g(y,w,t)$ gives the dependence of $s$ on $w$ and $t$, which are the two independent variables.

If the independent variables are $w, s$, then $\frac{\partial s}{\partial w} = 0$ and you just get $\frac{\partial h}{\partial w} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial w}$.

If the independent variables are $w, t$, then the equation is $$\dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} =\dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w} \times \dfrac{\partial w} {\partial w} + \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial t} \times \dfrac{\partial t} {\partial w} = \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial w}\times 1 + \dfrac{\partial h} {\partial t} \times 0$$
just as before.

You can mix and match the partials with respect to $w$ when $s$ and $t$ are the other independent variable, but the notation doesn't support it. If we add explanatory subscripts, it would show:
$$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w_t} =\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w_s} \times \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial w_t} + \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial s_w} \times \dfrac{\partial s}{\partial w_t}$$

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial w_t}$ is still $1$, but $\frac{\partial h}{\partial w_t} \ne \frac{\partial h}{\partial w_s}$, so the apparent contradiction is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when employing the chain rule you need to distinguish between differentiation using $w$:a-variable-in-the-expression-of-$h$ and $w$:just-the-second-argument-of-the-function-$g$.

$\small\qquad\begin{align}\partial_w h &=g'_1(x,w,g(y,w,t))~\partial_w x+g_2'(x,w,g(y,w,t))~\partial_w w+g'_3(x,w,g(y,w,t))~\partial_wg(y,w,t) \\[1ex] &=0+ g'_2\big(x,w,g(y,w,t)\big)+g'_3\big(x,w,g(y,w,t)\big)~\Big(0+g'_2(y,w,t)+g'_3(y,w,t)~\partial_wt\Big)\end{align}$

---

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial w}&=\dfrac{\partial g(x,w,s)}{\partial w}+\dfrac{\partial g(x,w,s)}{\partial s}\cdot\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial w}\\[1ex]&=\left.\dfrac{\partial g(x,w,s)}{\partial w}\right\rvert_{s=g(y,w,t)}+\left.\dfrac{\partial g(x,w,s)}{\partial s}\right\rvert_{s=g(x,w,t)}\left[\dfrac{\partial g(y,w,t)}{\partial w}+\dfrac{\partial g(y,w,t)}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial w}\right]\end{align}$$